# Write stream into buffer object

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs, node-streams

I have a stream that is being read from an audio source and I'm trying to store it into a `Buffer`. From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) that I've read, you are able to `pipe` the stream into one using `fs.createWriteStream(~buffer~)` instead of a file path.

I'm doing this currently as:

```
const outputBuffer = Buffer.alloc(150000)
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputBuffer)
```

but when I run it, it throws an error saying that the `Path: must be a string without null bytes` for the file system call.

If I'm misunderstanding the docs or missing something obvious please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `fs.createWriteStream()` is the filename to read. That is why you receive that particular error.

There is no way to read from a stream directly into an existing `Buffer`. There was [a node EP](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/pull/27) to support this, but it more or less died off because there are some potential gotchas with it.

For now you will need to either copy the bytes manually or if you don't want node to allocate extra Buffers, you will need to manually call `fs.open()`, `fs.read()` (this is the method that allows you to pass in your `Buffer` instance, along with an offset), and `fs.close()`.